# How to throw new ElementNotFoundException?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
int btnSize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("...")).size();

if ( btnSize > 1) {
    List<WebElement> b = driver.findElements(By.xpath("..."));
} else if (btnSize == 1){
    WebElement b = driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."));
} else {

    //How do I throw an Exception (e.g. ElementNotFoundException)
    //these variants did not work?

    throw ElementNotFoundException;     
    throw (new ElementNotFoundException);
    throw (new ElementNotFoundException("not found"));
    throw (new ElementNotFoundException(Exception e));
}
```

Comment: `throw new ElementNotFoundException("whatever");`

Comment: NoFoundElementException() is what works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Oracle Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html)**

*throw someThrowableObject;*

So, in your case-

```
throw new ElementNotFoundException("Not found!");
```

The keyword *new* is used to create an instance.

Answer (score 2):

When throwing a new Exception, basically you create an object by calling its constructor. So it's
 `throw new ElementNotFoundException("not found");` or
 `throw new ElementNotFoundException(exception)` 
 where exception is an Exception object you cought ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if/else` on `btnSize > 1`, and the `else` will throw the exception for you if `btnSize < 1`:

```
if (btnSize > 1)
{
    List<WebElement> b = driver.findElements(By.xpath("..."));
    ...
}
else
{
    WebElement b = driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")); // Might throw an exception
    ...
}
```

P.S.: You have not specified the `xpath` that you're using in each case, but I get the feeling that it's the same `xpath` in all three cases, and that you only want to iterate all the buttons, and perhaps return `true/false` according to the number of buttons.

If that is indeed the case, then you can simply do this instead:

```
List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("..."));
for (WebElement button : buttons)
{
    button.click(); // or whatever you wanna do with each button...
}
return buttons.size() > 0;
```